# Making a webbrowser request in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, loops

Hello i'm wondering how would one accomplish a form similar to this.

[image]

Now how would I make it go to URL amount of times I'm super new to programming so I'd like some help.

This is all I have
`Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Navigate ('Text.Box1')
End Sub
```

End Class`

Answer (score 0):

This is for navigating multiple times, why you now would want that:

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim y as Integer = CInt(TextBox2.Text)
For x = 0 To y
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
Next
```

And if you want it to navigate without a loop:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
```